# Spring Boot Actuator /health endpoint does not show database or file system information

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I cannot get database information or filesystem information to show up on the /health endpoint.  I only can get:

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

Details about my setup and configuration:
- Spring Boot 1.3.3
- Running the WAR on JBoss EAP 6.4
- Datasource is a JNDI resource.
- Oracle is the database

```
spring:
  datasource:
    # Must match the datasource name in JBoss standalone.xml
    jndi-name: java:jboss/beautiful-ds
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    properties:
      # escapes reserved words used as column names (if any)
      globally_quoted_identifiers: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
        naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

server:
  servlet-path: /*

management:
  health:
    diskspace:
      enabled: true
    db:
      enabled: true
endpoints.health.sensitive: false
```

One thing i found on /configprops is this, which I'm not sure whether it is related:

```
  "spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES": {
    "prefix": "spring.datasource",
    "properties": {
      "error": "Cannot serialize 'spring.datasource'"
    }
```

I had tried adding "driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" thinking it maybe needed more details, but that didn't change the situation.

so yeah, what gives?  I made a vanilla example project which at least shows the filesystem stuff out the gate, so not sure why either don't want to show in my "real" app.  Tell me your great and wise answers! :)

Answer (score 14):

By default Spring sets the below property to `never`. 
To be able to see full health details add the below property to your `application.properties`.

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Comment: In the beginning I thought there is a typo, since other properties start with `management.endpointS`. But you are right. Other useful value of the property is `when-authorized`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-health

Comment: IDEA suggests using property value `when_authorized` which works as well.

Answer (score 5):

From the `spring-boot` documentation:

> 45.6 Security with HealthIndicators
>
> Information returned by HealthIndicators is often somewhat sensitive in nature. For example,
>   you probably don’t want to publish details of your database server to
>   the world. For this reason, by default, only the health status is
>   exposed over an unauthenticated HTTP connection. If you are happy for
>   complete health information to always be exposed you can set
>   endpoints.health.sensitive to false. Health responses are also cached
>   to prevent “denial of service” attacks. Use the
>   endpoints.health.time-to-live property if you want to change the
>   default cache period of 1000 milliseconds.

Make sure to have following properties set.

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=true # Mark if the endpoint exposes sensitive information.
management.health.db.enabled=true # Enable database health check.
management.health.defaults.enabled=true # Enable default health indicators.
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true # Enable disk space health check.
```

Answer (score 5):

In cases if you are using spring security, then by default security is enabled for actuator endpoints, disable it in your yml file -

```
management:
    security:
           enabled: false
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, the aggregate health is shown under /health, at least (IIUC) for springboot2. Meaning, that even if you have everything configured just right, only one line will be shown.

UPDATE: and if this is not what you need, you have to specifically ask to see details. Check these settings:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=when-authorized
management.endpoint.health.roles=ADMIN
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed YAML and Properties syntax in your configuration file. Replace the last line by the following, and it should work:

```
endpoints:
    health:
        sensitive: false
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but believe it or not, I am able to toggle that value without issue using that properties syntax.  Changing that line to YAML format is behaving the same.  No new results on /heath.

Comment: Do you have security enabled?

Comment: I'm using the keycloak adaptor for spring boot.  I can get to all my endpoints fine.

Comment: I could see my endpoints, but to get details, still needed:
management.security.enabled=false

Comment: This is not the answer, last line in the code and proposed one both will work in same way.