# Can't get spring-boot /health indicator to display full content

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Trying to get the full content of the /health endpoint. I've set the following:

```
endpoints.health.sensitive=true
management.security.enabled=true
```

and I'm successfully authenticating (earlier, to gain access to the endpoint in the first place), as shown by the log snippet below:

```
2016-11-06 10:48:18,936 [XNIO-3 task-1]DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'endpoints.health.sensitive' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] with type [String] and value 'true'
2016-11-06 10:48:19,109 [XNIO-3 task-1]DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@4542ffee
2016-11-06 10:48:19,109 [XNIO-3 task-1]DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@760f603a: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@760f603a: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@375540cb: ......; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ......; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: .....' stored to HttpSession: 'io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl@768a4e99
2016-11-06 10:48:19,148 [XNIO-3 task-1]DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [UP {}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@eae8a50]
```

But one can see by the last line that I'm only being shown the "non-sensitive" information (there are db connections in the app which show up if I set both of the spring-boot properties to false.

From what I've read, the db status should be displayed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot Actuator /health endpoint does not show database or file system information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36428349/6372139)

I think you need to enable db health checks by default

```
management.health.db.enabled=true # Enable database health check.
management.health.defaults.enabled=true # Enable default health indicators.
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true # Enable disk space health check.
```

Also there are auto-configured health indicators for various backend implementations by Spring Boot

see: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators

Hope it helps.

Comment: but the db connection stuff shows if I set those two properties to false... are you saying that if they are true, then I need to set the db health check properties?

Comment: So to me it seems as if the security and sensitive properties disable them. You can give it a try and set management.health.db.enabled=true and see if these information appear again.

Comment: nope. I put the following in my properties file and still only see status:   endpoints.health.sensitive=true
management.security.enabled=true
management.health.db.enabled=true
management.health.defaults.enabled=true
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true

Answer (score 0):

put a breakpoint in HealthMvcEndpoint (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/mvc/HealthMvcEndpoint.java) and in debug, you'll be able to understand how the health response is built, based on the underlying components exposing health infos and the security config (exposeHealthDetails method).

Comment: Thanks @Vincent F. I did that, and it looks to me like there are a couple potential bugs/unreasonable limits. First, regarding authorization to govern visibility of the full data, the code requires that the user have the role **ROLE_ADMIN** - regardless of what role I said **should be** able to view the endpoint. Also, if I configure the endpoint with a .antMatchers("/health").permitAll() configuration, seems to me the code would consider this endpoint "not secure", but it doesn't.

Comment: My options seem to be to create an **ADMIN** role in our AD (not going to happen, or already exists with a bunch of people that don't care about this endpoint) or completely remove Spring Security from the app... also not going to happen. I'm stuck unless I modify the code locally.

Comment: there's a way of "hacking it" - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800151/bypass-cas-to-get-un-secured-health-infos-from-spring-boot-app/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property in the properties file to resolve the problem:

```
management.health.db.enabled=true
```