# bypass CAS to get un/secured health infos from Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot app using CAS WebSecurity to make sure that all incoming non authenticated requests are redirected to a common login page.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CASWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

I want to expose health endpoints through actuator, and added the relevant dependency. I want to bypass the CAS check for these /health URL which are going to be used by monitoring tools, so in the configure method, I have added :

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll();
```

This works, but now I want to tweak it further :

- detailed health status (ie "full content" as per the docs) should be accessible only to some specific monitoring user, for which credentials are provided in property file.
- if no authentication is provided, then "status only" should be returned.

Following http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-health-access-restrictions, I've configured the properties as below, so that it should work :

```
management.security.enabled: true
endpoints.health.sensitive: false
```

But I have a problem with how I configure the credentials... following  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints , I added in my config file :

```
security.user.name: admin
security.user.password: secret
```

But it's not working - and when I don't put the properties, I don't see the password generated in logs.

So I'm trying to put some custom properties like

```
healthcheck.username: healthCheckMonitoring
healthcheck.password: healthPassword
```

and inject these into my Security config so that configureGlobal method becomes :

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
                            CasAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(healthcheckUsername).password(healthcheckPassword).roles("ADMIN");
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

and in the configure method, I change the config for the URL pattern to :

```
   http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/health/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
        .and().httpBasic()
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().csrf().disable();
```

With that config, I get full content when authenticated, but logically, I don't get any status (UP or DOWN) when I'm not authenticated, because the request doesn't even reach the endpoint : it is intercepted and rejected by the security config.

How can I tweak my Spring Security config so that this works properly ? I have the feeling I should somehow chain the configs, with the CAS config first allowing the request to go through purely based on the URL, so that the request then hits a second config that will do basic http authentication if credentials are provided, or let the request hit the endpoint unauthenticated otherwise, so that I get the "status only" result.. But at the same time, I'm thinking Spring Boot can manage this correctly if I configure it properly..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is not great, but so far, that's what works for me :

in my config (only the relevant code):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CASWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //disable HTTP Session management
    http
        .securityContext()
        .securityContextRepository(new NullSecurityContextRepository())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().disable();

    http.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache());

    //no security checks for health checks
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health/**").permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();

    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());

    http // login configuration
        .addFilter(authenticationFilter())
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
}
```

Then I added a specific filter :

```
@Component
public class HealthcheckSimpleStatusFilter  extends GenericFilterBean {

private final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME="Authorization";

private final String URL_PATH = "/health";

@Value("${healthcheck.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${healthcheck.password}")
private String password;

private String healthcheckRole="ADMIN";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = this.getAsHttpRequest(request);

    //doing it only for /health endpoint.
    if(URL_PATH.equals(httpRequest.getServletPath())) {

        String authHeader = httpRequest.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            String[] tokens = extractAndDecodeHeader(authHeader);
            if (tokens != null && tokens.length == 2 && username.equals(tokens[0]) && password.equals(tokens[1])) {
                createUserContext(username, password, healthcheckRole, httpRequest);
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials");
            }
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

/**
 * setting the authenticated user in Spring context so that {@link HealthMvcEndpoint} knows later on that this is an authorized user
 * @param username
 * @param password
 * @param role
 * @param httpRequest
 */
private void createUserContext(String username, String password, String role,HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authoritiesForAnonymous = new ArrayList<>();
    authoritiesForAnonymous.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    UserDetails userDetails = new User(username, password, authoritiesForAnonymous);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}

private HttpServletRequest getAsHttpRequest(ServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        throw new ServletException("Expecting an HTTP request");
    }
    return (HttpServletRequest) request;
}

private String[] extractAndDecodeHeader(String header) throws IOException {
    byte[] base64Token = header.substring(6).getBytes("UTF-8");

    byte[] decoded;
    try {
        decoded = Base64.decode(base64Token);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException var7) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Failed to decode basic authentication token",var7);
    }

    String token = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
    int delim = token.indexOf(":");
    if(delim == -1) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid basic authentication token");
    } else {
        return new String[]{token.substring(0, delim), token.substring(delim + 1)};
    }
}

}
```